# GO TO DEFINITION from Javascript file not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript1.6

`In Visual Studio 2013 Premium`, when I'm in a JavaScript File and have let say a `TypeScript` class named `MyClass`.  At the end of the TS file I instantiate it like this :

```
var MyInstanceClass = MyClass
```

Now MyInstanceClass can be used everywhere.  What I'm trying to understand is why from a JavaScript file I'm using this instance like this

```
MyInstanceClass.MyMethod();
```

but when I try to use GO TO DEFINITION for `MyMethod` I get

**Go to definition failed.  Either the caret is already at the definition or because an explicit definition could not be found**

I tried on `MyInstanceClass` rather than the method and I get the same thing.